# Can I inherit first non-transparent background-color for the element?

Tags: html, css

Can I inherit first non-transparent background-color for the element with only css rule? For example if I need some element to be non-transparent inside some other element with background-color but it's nested into some other transparent elements.

Answer (score 4):

No.

The only element you can inherit a value from is the immediate parent.

The closest you could come would be to use JavaScript to search the DOM for an element with a computed value for that property which isn't transparent and then apply it to the current element.

You'd probably be better off with CSS rulesets that use descendant combinators such as:

```
.example,
.example .solid {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: if I have 2-3 nested divs can a set inherit for all of them?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: I mean if some div has background-color set by bootstrap for example, and there are <div><div><mydiv></mydiv></div></div> inside, will setting background-color inherit for all of them

Comment: Since the default value for `background-color` is not inherit, no, it won't inherit for anything of them.